# Error Starting Pentaho BIserver

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

Im running `Pentaho 5.3 Biserver` in a Redhat machine yesterday there was a power failure, when the power came back i tried to start the biserver it gives

```
HTTP Status 404 -
type Status report
message
description The requested resource is not available.
```

Apache Tomcat/6.0.411

I checked the Pentaho.log

```
2015-03-24 12:11:23,595 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.osgi.OSGIBoot] Error installing Bundle
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: org.objectweb.asm.all:4.0.0
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.createRevision(BundleImpl.java:1233)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.<init>(BundleImpl.java:96)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2899)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:138)
    at org.pentaho.platform.osgi.OSGIBoot.startup(OSGIBoot.java:137)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:421)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:412)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.runAsSystem(PentahoSystem.java:391)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:412)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.access$000(PentahoSystem.java:77)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:343)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:340)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.runAsSystem(PentahoSystem.java:391)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:340)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:311)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:212)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
2015-03-24 12:11:23,609 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.osgi.OSGIBoot] Error installing Bundle
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging:1.1.1
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.createRevision(BundleImpl.java:1233)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.<init>(BundleImpl.java:96)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2899)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:138)
    at org.pentaho.platform.osgi.OSGIBoot.startup(OSGIBoot.java:137)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:421)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:412)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.runAsSystem(PentahoSystem.java:391)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:412)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.access$000(PentahoSystem.java:77)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:343)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:340)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.runAsSystem(PentahoSystem.java:391)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:340)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:311)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:212)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

How do i resolve this? Help please

Comment: try removing:
/biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/lib/pentaho-hadoop-hive-jdbc-shim-5.2.0.0-209.jar   It was mentioned in http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?175685-Pentaho-5-2-Listener-boot-error-with-MySql

Comment: does it work? If so I can post it as an answer

Comment: Thanks David, But my server components has crashed, So i redeployed them and got them back. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should clean your osgi cache
1) stop pentaho server
2) go to /biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/osgi/cache and delete everything
3) start pentaho server

Comment: use lowercase for pentaho (localhost:8080/pentaho)